# How to fixture a product with attribute options in EcomDev PHPUnit?

Tags: product-attribute, ecomdev-phpunit

I want to write a fixture for some products. The attribute `my_attribute` is of type `eav/entity_attribute_source_table`. The Options are not created by install scripts, so they are not in the test database.

How can I get EcomDev to create the needed options for `my_attribute`? I don't want to set a fixture on `eav_attribute_option*` tables because that would delete the options of all other attributes.

```
eav:
  catalog_product:
    - entity_id: 1
      sku: 359
      name: Product 1
      my_attribute: Option 1 #This option is to be generated
      type_id: simple
      price: 55
      visibility: 4
      status: 1
      website_ids:
        - base
```

Comment: do you want the install script to run again?

Comment: No, I want that the option is created just for the unit test.

Comment: As far as I know, the fixture you are describing is the only option.

Comment: As a reference, here is a link to a fixture on the `eav_attribute_option` tables: https://github.com/IvanChepurnyi/EcomDev_PHPUnit/commit/9264db771772899ecdb9a4a5b2e58073eac29251#commitcomment-8629616

Comment: @Simon: It moved here: https://github.com/EcomDev/EcomDev_PHPUnit/commit/9264db771772899ecdb9a4a5b2e58073eac29251#commitcomment-8629616

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know you need to set a fixture on the eav_entity_attribute_option tables.

Since EcomDev_PHPUnit copies the database to a test table, your original database still will be intact, unless you have configured EcomDev_PHPUnit to use the original database (which is not a good idea).
Because of this the truncation of the table should not be an issue.

If you need this complex fixtures, maybe it is easier to mock more of Magento to get around them?
Generally I try to avoid complex fixtures if possible.

Comment: Thanks! But there is no `eav_entity_attribute_option` table. Which ones do you mean exactly? Mocking the attribute options is also a nice idea, not sure how this would work though...

Comment: Do table fixtures not truncate the table anymore when applied?

Comment: @fschmengler just checked and can confirm that a table fixture on `eav_attribute_option` and `eav_attribute_option_value` truncates the tables.

Comment: But the truncation only happens in the testing DB, not in your development db, so that shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Learning to create mocks and to register them with Magento so they are used instead of the real things is a most valuable investment of time.